# Generate Property for ValidationRule for dynamically added TextBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm reading DataBase Columns from my DataBase and I generate a TextBox for each Column.

Now I want to add different ValidationRules. For example a ValidationRule for required fields, for example, if `AllowDBNull` is false, then the field is required and I need to add a ValidationRule.

The ValidationRule is the following:

```
public class NotEmptyValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((value ?? "").ToString())
            ? new ValidationResult(false, "Field is required.")
            : ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

Then I loop throug my `DataTable schmeaTable` which is filled with `schemaTable = dataReader.GetSchemaTable();`. and for each row in the table I save the `ColumnName`, `DataType`, `ColumnSize (Length)` and the `AllowDBNull` property to variables.
For each row which is `NOT NULL` in the DataBase, I create a binding for the ValidationRule.

```
foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
{
    bool AllowDBNull = row.Field<Boolean>("AllowDBNull");
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.Name = row["ColumnName"].ToString();
    if(!AllowDBNull)
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
        binding.NotifyOnValidationError = true;
        binding.ValidationRules.Add(new NotEmptyValidationRule());
        // binding.Path = ???
        textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
    }
}
```

But I also need to set the Path to the Property which I can't create because I never know which properties I will have.

I can have 5 Columns in the DataBase which different names, or I can have 10 Columns or more/less with different names.

My ViewModel contains only the PropertyChanged Event:

```
public class TextFieldViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private Action<PropertyChangedEventArgs> RaisePropertyChanged()
    {
        return args => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
    }
}
```

So how can I set the `Binding.Path` to a property which have to be generated dynamically in the `foreach loop` where I create the TextBox?

Comment: You are creating a TextBox for each *row*, aren't you? So the question is which column you want to bind it to.

Comment: @mm8 I create a TextBox for each Column in my DataBase (or for each Row in DataBase schema). I want to bind all TextBoxes (DataBase Columns) which have the property "NOT NULL" in the DataBase to the ValidationRule.

Comment: So you want to bind the TextBox to the column named "ColumnName"?

Comment: Or what value are you intending to edit in the TextBox?

Comment: @mm8 `schemaTable` is a DataTable which contains the schema of the current database table. I created a image for better understanding: [link](https://imgur.com/a/G9HeX). U see I got 3 Columns (without id). So there will be 3 TextBoxes. Now I want to bind only this one, who has `Null = Nein (no)`. So I need to generate a Property for this field in code to bind the ValidationRule to it.

Comment: You don't "generate" a property dynamically. The TextBox needs a DataContext to bind to.

Comment: That's the question. To bind the ValidationRule to a TextBox I need to set the Path. But I can't set the Path because i have no property which I can't just write in my ViewModel because the columnname can be "telephone" instead of "firstname" or "lastname" can be "NULL  = No" instead of "NULL = YES". I hope u understood now what my problem is and why im searching help here :D

Comment: What's your SELECT statement for the schemaTable?

Comment: A simple `SELECT * FROM tablename`.

Comment: Then you don't get a row per column...

Comment: Of course I do. Because it's working. The only thing which is not working is the binding because I dont know how to create a property dynamically which I can bind to my dynamically added TextBox. If I have 4 Columns there will be 4 TextBoxes with the placeholder of the `ColumnName`. If I have 10 Columns than there will be 10 TextBoxes. This works fine. I will send u the SQL Code in a chat to avoid spam.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167347/discussion-between-kushgene-and-mm8).